# Sequences with Alternating signs map into an interval

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the space of sequences:
$$
\mathcal{E} = \{\{\epsilon_n\}_{n= 1}^{\infty}: \epsilon_n = \pm 1\}
$$
This can be considered a "random choice of sign" in the probabilistic context for example. Given this, someone has proposed to me the following question. Is the map:

$$
f: \mathcal{E} \to \left[-\frac{\pi^2}{6},\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right]
$$

given by:

$$
\{\epsilon_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon_n}{n^2}
$$
a surjection? Put another way, does any real number $$x\in \left [ -\frac{\pi^2}{6},\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right]$$ have an expansion:
$$
x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon_n}{n^2}?
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0$ doesn't belong to the image of $f$ as $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\epsilon_n}{n^2} \in [-0.7, 0.7].$$

So if $\epsilon_1=1$, $f(\{\epsilon_n\}) \in [0.3, 1.7]$ and if $\epsilon_1=-1$, $f(\{\epsilon_n\}) \in [-1.7, -0.3]$.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\approx 1.644}$, I'm not sure how you could get $\frac{3}{10}$. If $\varepsilon_1=1$ and each other $\varepsilon_i=-1$, $i\geq 2$, seems like you can't traverse the distance of $\frac{7}{10}$.